# How to update a dialogue window after setting an attribute?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

In my firefox addon, I have a little non-modal window that stays open whilst the user browses.  The addon also has a toolbar.  When a button is pushed on the toolbar, a function is called that sets the value of certain attributes in the window.

Now, in my code, I can call the function just fine, but the window never changes.

However, I call the same function with an `onload` listener, and it works fine there.  I put an `alert` in the function, and it does get called, but the changes never show in the window.

How can I make sure the changes are shown on my window?  Here is some of my sample code:

```
    var windowManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
    var mywindow = windowManager.getMostRecentWindow('mywindow');
    if (mywindow) {
        alert("found it!");
        var thislabel = document.getElementById("mylabel");
        thislabel.setAttribute("label", "New Text");
    } else { 
        alert("The window is not open.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m kind of guessing here, but maybe you need to access the right document?

```
var thislabel = mywindow.document.getElementById("mylabel");

// alert something if the element was found
thislabel !== null && alert('found');
```

Comment: That was it! The function was called, but it was missing a handle to the window.  Thank you!

Comment: Hmm.. That does work, and I am pleased to have marked the answer, but it seems to not update the window sometimes, even though the function is called. Any clue?